# Move File within Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to move a file within Vim? E.g. I opened a file foo/bar.txt in Vim. I know 2 ways to move this file:

First solution:

1. Delete the buffer with `:bd bar.txt`
2. Perform the move on the shell with `mv foo/bar.txt foo/bar2.txt`
3. Load the file in vim with `:e foo/bar2.txt`

Second solution:

1. Close Vim, so all buffer where closed.
2. Perform the move on the shell...
3. Start Vim and load the file.

But these two solutions are embarrassing. I know, there is a plugin for renaming files [vim-enuch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-eunuch), but isn't there a Vim way for performing such basic functionality?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no atomic way to move a file like that, but this should be close:

```
function! MoveFile(newspec)
     let old = expand('%')
     " could be improved:
     if (old == a:newspec)
         return 0
     endif
     exe 'sav' fnameescape(a:newspec)
     call delete(old)
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=file -bar MoveFile call MoveFile('<args>')
```

Now you could say:

```
:MoveFile file2.txt
```

To rename to file2.txt

```
:MoveFile %.0
```

to move file2.txt to file2.txt.0

Comment: This solution is better, because I can add this lines 5 to my vimrc rather than loading a heavyweight plugin.

Comment: Filename escaping issues are airily ignored in the provided implementation.  To fix it in this regard, one should change the last two lines of the function as follows.  First, `exe 'sav' fnameescape(a:newspec)`; second, `call delete(old)`.  It is also judicious to check the return value of the `delete()` function to inform the user in case of failure removing file (ease of catching this situation is another advantage of the function over `!rm`, besides its cross-platformness).

Comment: Also, it is probably useful to specify `-complete=file` when defining the command to enable filename completion.  And, maybe, `-bar`, too.

Comment: @ib. Great tip. You can tell I don't actually author scripts much.

Comment: @ib. With respect to the quoting issue... you deserve half the rep here :)

Comment: Would be cool to detect if the destination is a directory, and move with the current name in that case, like `mv file dir`.

Comment: @SvenK, netrw is not a heavy-weight plugin. It comes installed by default with VIM :)

Comment: There is an atomic way to move a file with function "rename", see :h rename( but you have to close the buffer and open the new created file.

Answer (score 53):

You could also use netrw (the default file explorer) rename functionality.

1. Open netrw with `:E`
2. Move your cursor to the line with the file you intend to rename, in this case bar.txt . You move to the file in question using h,j,k,l or you can search for it with `/` (e.g. `/bar.txt`)
3. Hit `R`. You will then be prompted for a new filepath. When done entering the filepath hit `<CR>`
4. Move your cursor to the new file and open it with `<CR>`

While this solution may not be as quick as using vim-eunch, it does allow you to see the project's structure as you rename the file. This will also allow you to move multiple files at once.

For further reading run `:help netrw-move`

Comment: One can also open file explorer with (`:Sex` or `:Vex`) if one has :E command remapped to something.

Answer (score 6):

if you're in the bar.txt buffer:

```
:w bar2.txt
:!rm bar.txt
```

If *bar2.txt* already exists in the current directory, use `:w!`.

Comment: But `!rm bar.txt` doesn't close the open buffer

Comment: that's true, change the `:sav` to a `:w`

Comment: The buffer for `bar.txt` will still be open. It could be closed with `bd <BUFFER_NUM>`.

Comment: I fail to understand why `:sav` was replaced by `:w` in the edit: `:w` just creates the new file, but the buffer still has the old file open. Peforming the `:w ... :!rm` sequence thus gives the error `File "..." no longer available`. If you use `:sav`, the buffer will have the new file open before you do `:!rm`, so no error is triggered.